# Can't Find Tuple Method

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a Net 4.6.2 console app which uses a Net Standard 2.0 library I've written. One of the methods in the library returns a tuple:

```
public (ScanStatEntry scanEntry, DateTime nextScan) Run()
{
```

The routine is called from within the console app as follows:

```
(ScanStatEntry scanEntry, DateTime nextScan) = _scanner.Run();
```

This all worked fine for quite some time...until suddenly I started getting the following exception when the console app ran:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.ValueTuple`2<Olbert.CommunityScanner.Data.Entities.ScanStatEntry,System.DateTime>
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Scanner.Run()'.    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.ScannerService.RunAndWait()    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.ScannerService.Start() in
>   C:\Programming\CommunityScanner\CommunityScannerTopShelf\ScannerService.cs:line
>   70    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Program.<>c.b__0_2(ScannerService tc) in
>   C:\Programming\CommunityScanner\CommunityScannerTopShelf\Program.cs:line
>   20    at
>   Topshelf.ServiceConfiguratorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<WhenStarted>b__0(T
>   service, HostControl control)    at
>   Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1.DelegateServiceHandle.Start(HostControl
>   hostControl)    at Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost.Run()

I don't know what I did to cause this problem to appear. Also, everything compiles fine, with no errors; it just crashes as soon as execution tries to enter the method within which the `_scanner.Run()` call is located (e.g., the containing class' constructor executes just fine).

In researching this, I realized that I had never installed the `System.ValueTuple` NuGet package for the console app...which I thought was a requirement when using tuples in Net 4.6.2, although, if so, I don't know why the app used to run fine.

So I tried adding the package. No joy; same compile okay but crash on execution claiming the method can't be found.

Calling another method in that same Net Standard 2.0 library works fine. It's just the method that returns a tuple that causes the problem. I could work around this by returning an object rather than a tuple, but I'm curious as to what's causing the problem, and why it appeared after everything was working fine for so long.

Comment: _"I don't know what I did to cause this problem to appear"_ -- well, we're not going to be able to know either. We have less information than you do! `MissingMethodException` is always the same: you've got an out-of-date assembly (or in rare cases, a newer one where the method has been removed). You'll need to investigate this one yourself, paying close attention to exactly what assemblies are loaded and where they come from, until you can find out why your code is using the wrong package.

Comment: We need to be able to take the code you have posted and compile it and reproduce the issue. We cannot do that with the code you have posted.

Comment: Like @CodingYoshi says, this question needs, at a minimum, a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces it. Though, I suspect even with that, we can't diagnose it. It's likely to be specific to your project or even your PC configuration. That said: is the error message above _exactly_ as it was emitted? Because the "method" that's missing appears to be a constructor (there's just the type name in the error message). Which isn't a versioning issue so much as a corrupted assembly issue, I'd think.

Answer (score 2):

Several more hours researching this problem online led me into discussions about problems associated with automatic binding redirects. Apparently, those can arise when you are mixing net standard and net traditional assemblies, which themselves depend upon other assemblies that may depend on different versions of other assemblies.

In my net traditional console app automatic redirect was set in the csproj file (old style format, first PropertyGroup):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{B64EE74D-F171-4438-8E7A-ACAE7B40C6C8}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Olbert.CommunityScanner</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CommunityScannerTopShelf</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Setting AutoGeneratedBindingRedirects to false solved the problem of the application crashing, and let me step into the Net Standard class library method that was returning a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but if someone still have this problem and come by this thread, we solved it by adding multiple framework targets to the csproj file of the .net-standard project.

That way the compiler compiles a version for each framework and links the correct one.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

PS: note that it's TargetFrameworkS, plural.